# Installation from USB goes fine, cannot get past login after 1st boot

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

I've managed to install elementary OS fine to a SSD (machines specs below) on my computer, there is no other OS installed. After the fist boot and filling in my password at the login manager I get dropped straight to a desktop with no dock, no menubar, no icons...just a desktop picture. I cannot change to a console terminal, all I have is a mouse cursor. This has happened 3 times now on a completely cleaned SSD. I usually start with a clean GPT formatted disk.

I've tried to boot from the USB installer and chroot'ed into the / on the internal drive, though I cannot run updates as network settings do not persist through to the chroot environment (why not? in Arch it does?)

Any help would be appreciated.

Install medium - Freya 0.3.2
UEFI install (no MBR installs for GFX card bios)
Motherboard - Gigabyte z97 chipset
GFX card - NVidia 970
Wifi TPLink N600 USB adapter (Ralink chipset driver works fine from kernel) 
Sound - onboard
Shasum checks fine.

Answer (score 1):

It appears it's an issue with grub.

In order to boot to a (working) desktop you have to alter the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file and remove 'quiet' from the default boot option kernel line and replace with 'nomodeset'.